# Accessing intra-day time series data from Fitbit Surge does not work

Tags: fitbit

I am trying to follow along a tutorial for accessing the intra-day time series of my Fitbit Surge:

http://shishu.info/2016/06/how-to-download-your-fitbit-second-level-data-without-coding/

I selected the "Callback-URL": https://127.0.0.1:8080/ in the registration page of my app.

When I opened the "OAuth 2.0 tutorial page" in my browser, I inserted the credentials of my App into the page. I used the "Redirect URI": https://127.0.0.1:8080/. Then, I clicked on the generated authorization link.

When the new page opened inside the browser, I got the following error message string displayed instead of a result: "Developer information: invalid_request - Missing parameters: client_id"

I do not understand why this problem occurs, as I took the "OAuth 2.0 Client ID" from the app as the client ID.

Can anyone help who also went into this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Change your "OAuth 2.0 Application Type" setting on https://dev.fitbit.com/apps to "Client".

Change Callback-URL": 127.0.0.1:8080 to public url.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that doesn't help either.

Comment: "Callback-URL": https://127.0.0.1:8080 should be changed to public url. Yout local system url will not be accessible by fitbit.